# Python simulate keydown

Tags: python, windows, keypress, keydown, simulate

After searching for several hours i´m wondering if its possible to simulate a keydown press on the keyboard. For example I want my program to hold the <kbd>x</kbd> key down for five seconds so when I run it in notepad it would look like to see something like this: `xxxxxxxxxxxxx`. I tried around with different pieces of code on the internet, the best thing I could find so far is this:

```
import ctypes
import time
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
inputhex = raw_input("Please enter your desired key's code (HEX): ")
keycode = int(inputhex, 16)
time.sleep(1)
#VOID keybd_event(BYTE bVk, BYTE bScan, DWORD dwFlags, PTR dwExtraInfo);
user32.keybd_event(keycode,0,2,0) #is the code for KEYDOWN
time.sleep(5)
#user32.keybd_event(keycode,0,0,0) #is the code for KEYDUP[/code]
```

The Sendkey module doesn't solve my problem either becuase it only allows you to send a single keypress and not a hold key down event. I know about autoit, used it in the past, but I just really want to know if this is possible with python and how.
P.S. i'm using python for windows

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This code should get you started. `ctypes` is used heavily. At the bottom, you will see example code.

```
import ctypes

LONG = ctypes.c_long
DWORD = ctypes.c_ulong
ULONG_PTR = ctypes.POINTER(DWORD)
WORD = ctypes.c_ushort

class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('dx', LONG),
                ('dy', LONG),
                ('mouseData', DWORD),
                ('dwFlags', DWORD),
                ('time', DWORD),
                ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR))
                
class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('wVk', WORD),
                ('wScan', WORD),
                ('dwFlags', DWORD),
                ('time', DWORD),
                ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR))
                
class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('uMsg', DWORD),
                ('wParamL', WORD),
                ('wParamH', WORD))
                
class _INPUTunion(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = (('mi', MOUSEINPUT),
                ('ki', KEYBDINPUT),
                ('hi', HARDWAREINPUT))
                
class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('type', DWORD),
                ('union', _INPUTunion))
                
def SendInput(*inputs):
    nInputs = len(inputs)
    LPINPUT = INPUT * nInputs
    pInputs = LPINPUT(*inputs)
    cbSize = ctypes.c_int(ctypes.sizeof(INPUT))
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(nInputs, pInputs, cbSize)

INPUT_MOUSE = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2
    
def Input(structure):
    if isinstance(structure, MOUSEINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_MOUSE, _INPUTunion(mi=structure))
    if isinstance(structure, KEYBDINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_KEYBOARD, _INPUTunion(ki=structure))
    if isinstance(structure, HARDWAREINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_HARDWARE, _INPUTunion(hi=structure))
    raise TypeError('Cannot create INPUT structure!')

WHEEL_DELTA = 120
XBUTTON1 = 0x0001
XBUTTON2 = 0x0002
MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL = 0x01000
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008
MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020
MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040
MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000
MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800
MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080
MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100

def MouseInput(flags, x, y, data):
    return MOUSEINPUT(x, y, data, flags, 0, None)

VK_LBUTTON = 0x01               # Left mouse button
VK_RBUTTON = 0x02               # Right mouse button
VK_CANCEL = 0x03                # Control-break processing
VK_MBUTTON = 0x04               # Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
VK_XBUTTON1 = 0x05              # X1 mouse button
VK_XBUTTON2 = 0x06              # X2 mouse button
VK_BACK = 0x08                  # BACKSPACE key
VK_TAB = 0x09                   # TAB key
VK_CLEAR = 0x0C                 # CLEAR key
VK_RETURN = 0x0D                # ENTER key
VK_SHIFT = 0x10                 # SHIFT key
VK_CONTROL = 0x11               # CTRL key
VK_MENU = 0x12                  # ALT key
VK_PAUSE = 0x13                 # PAUSE key
VK_CAPITAL = 0x14               # CAPS LOCK key
VK_KANA = 0x15                  # IME Kana mode
VK_HANGUL = 0x15                # IME Hangul mode
VK_JUNJA = 0x17                 # IME Junja mode
VK_FINAL = 0x18                 # IME final mode
VK_HANJA = 0x19                 # IME Hanja mode
VK_KANJI = 0x19                 # IME Kanji mode
VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B                # ESC key
VK_CONVERT = 0x1C               # IME convert
VK_NONCONVERT = 0x1D            # IME nonconvert
VK_ACCEPT = 0x1E                # IME accept
VK_MODECHANGE = 0x1F            # IME mode change request
VK_SPACE = 0x20                 # SPACEBAR
VK_PRIOR = 0x21                 # PAGE UP key
VK_NEXT = 0x22                  # PAGE DOWN key
VK_END = 0x23                   # END key
VK_HOME = 0x24                  # HOME key
VK_LEFT = 0x25                  # LEFT ARROW key
VK_UP = 0x26                    # UP ARROW key
VK_RIGHT = 0x27                 # RIGHT ARROW key
VK_DOWN = 0x28                  # DOWN ARROW key
VK_SELECT = 0x29                # SELECT key
VK_PRINT = 0x2A                 # PRINT key
VK_EXECUTE = 0x2B               # EXECUTE key
VK_SNAPSHOT = 0x2C              # PRINT SCREEN key
VK_INSERT = 0x2D                # INS key
VK_DELETE = 0x2E                # DEL key
VK_HELP = 0x2F                  # HELP key
VK_LWIN = 0x5B                  # Left Windows key (Natural keyboard)
VK_RWIN = 0x5C                  # Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)
VK_APPS = 0x5D                  # Applications key (Natural keyboard)
VK_SLEEP = 0x5F                 # Computer Sleep key
VK_NUMPAD0 = 0x60               # Numeric keypad 0 key
VK_NUMPAD1 = 0x61               # Numeric keypad 1 key
VK_NUMPAD2 = 0x62               # Numeric keypad 2 key
VK_NUMPAD3 = 0x63               # Numeric keypad 3 key
VK_NUMPAD4 = 0x64               # Numeric keypad 4 key
VK_NUMPAD5 = 0x65               # Numeric keypad 5 key
VK_NUMPAD6 = 0x66               # Numeric keypad 6 key
VK_NUMPAD7 = 0x67               # Numeric keypad 7 key
VK_NUMPAD8 = 0x68               # Numeric keypad 8 key
VK_NUMPAD9 = 0x69               # Numeric keypad 9 key
VK_MULTIPLY = 0x6A              # Multiply key
VK_ADD = 0x6B                   # Add key
VK_SEPARATOR = 0x6C             # Separator key
VK_SUBTRACT = 0x6D              # Subtract key
VK_DECIMAL = 0x6E               # Decimal key
VK_DIVIDE = 0x6F                # Divide key
VK_F1 = 0x70                    # F1 key
VK_F2 = 0x71                    # F2 key
VK_F3 = 0x72                    # F3 key
VK_F4 = 0x73                    # F4 key
VK_F5 = 0x74                    # F5 key
VK_F6 = 0x75                    # F6 key
VK_F7 = 0x76                    # F7 key
VK_F8 = 0x77                    # F8 key
VK_F9 = 0x78                    # F9 key
VK_F10 = 0x79                   # F10 key
VK_F11 = 0x7A                   # F11 key
VK_F12 = 0x7B                   # F12 key
VK_F13 = 0x7C                   # F13 key
VK_F14 = 0x7D                   # F14 key
VK_F15 = 0x7E                   # F15 key
VK_F16 = 0x7F                   # F16 key
VK_F17 = 0x80                   # F17 key
VK_F18 = 0x81                   # F18 key
VK_F19 = 0x82                   # F19 key
VK_F20 = 0x83                   # F20 key
VK_F21 = 0x84                   # F21 key
VK_F22 = 0x85                   # F22 key
VK_F23 = 0x86                   # F23 key
VK_F24 = 0x87                   # F24 key
VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90               # NUM LOCK key
VK_SCROLL = 0x91                # SCROLL LOCK key
VK_LSHIFT = 0xA0                # Left SHIFT key
VK_RSHIFT = 0xA1                # Right SHIFT key
VK_LCONTROL = 0xA2              # Left CONTROL key
VK_RCONTROL = 0xA3              # Right CONTROL key
VK_LMENU = 0xA4                 # Left MENU key
VK_RMENU = 0xA5                 # Right MENU key
VK_BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6          # Browser Back key
VK_BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7       # Browser Forward key
VK_BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8       # Browser Refresh key
VK_BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9          # Browser Stop key
VK_BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA        # Browser Search key
VK_BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB     # Browser Favorites key
VK_BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC          # Browser Start and Home key
VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD           # Volume Mute key
VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE           # Volume Down key
VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF             # Volume Up key
VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0      # Next Track key
VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1      # Previous Track key
VK_MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2            # Stop Media key
VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3      # Play/Pause Media key
VK_LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4           # Start Mail key
VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5   # Select Media key
VK_LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6           # Start Application 1 key
VK_LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7           # Start Application 2 key
VK_OEM_1 = 0xBA                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the ';:' key
VK_OEM_PLUS = 0xBB              # For any country/region, the '+' key
VK_OEM_COMMA = 0xBC             # For any country/region, the ',' key
VK_OEM_MINUS = 0xBD             # For any country/region, the '-' key
VK_OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE            # For any country/region, the '.' key
VK_OEM_2 = 0xBF                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the '/?' key
VK_OEM_3 = 0xC0                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the '`~' key
VK_OEM_4 = 0xDB                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the '[{' key
VK_OEM_5 = 0xDC                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the '\|' key
VK_OEM_6 = 0xDD                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the ']}' key
VK_OEM_7 = 0xDE                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
                                # For the US standard keyboard, the 'single-quote/double-quote' key
VK_OEM_8 = 0xDF                 # Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
VK_OEM_102 = 0xE2               # Either the angle bracket key or the backslash key on the RT 102-key keyboard
VK_PROCESSKEY = 0xE5            # IME PROCESS key
VK_PACKET = 0xE7                # Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes. The VK_PACKET key is the low word of a 32-bit Virtual Key value used for non-keyboard input methods. For more information, see Remark in KEYBDINPUT, SendInput, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_KEYUP
VK_ATTN = 0xF6                  # Attn key
VK_CRSEL = 0xF7                 # CrSel key
VK_EXSEL = 0xF8                 # ExSel key
VK_EREOF = 0xF9                 # Erase EOF key
VK_PLAY = 0xFA                  # Play key
VK_ZOOM = 0xFB                  # Zoom key
VK_PA1 = 0xFD                   # PA1 key
VK_OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE             # Clear key

KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004

KEY_0 = 0x30
KEY_1 = 0x31
KEY_2 = 0x32
KEY_3 = 0x33
KEY_4 = 0x34
KEY_5 = 0x35
KEY_6 = 0x36
KEY_7 = 0x37
KEY_8 = 0x38
KEY_9 = 0x39
KEY_A = 0x41
KEY_B = 0x42
KEY_C = 0x43
KEY_D = 0x44
KEY_E = 0x45
KEY_F = 0x46
KEY_G = 0x47
KEY_H = 0x48
KEY_I = 0x49
KEY_J = 0x4A
KEY_K = 0x4B
KEY_L = 0x4C
KEY_M = 0x4D
KEY_N = 0x4E
KEY_O = 0x4F
KEY_P = 0x50
KEY_Q = 0x51
KEY_R = 0x52
KEY_S = 0x53
KEY_T = 0x54
KEY_U = 0x55
KEY_V = 0x56
KEY_W = 0x57
KEY_X = 0x58
KEY_Y = 0x59
KEY_Z = 0x5A

def KeybdInput(code, flags):
    return KEYBDINPUT(code, code, flags, 0, None)

def HardwareInput(message, parameter):
    return HARDWAREINPUT(message & 0xFFFFFFFF,
                         parameter & 0xFFFF,
                         parameter >> 16 & 0xFFFF)

def Mouse(flags, x=0, y=0, data=0):
    return Input(MouseInput(flags, x, y, data))

def Keyboard(code, flags=0):
    return Input(KeybdInput(code, flags))

def Hardware(message, parameter=0):
    return Input(HardwareInput(message, parameter))

################################################################################

import string

UPPER = frozenset('~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?')
LOWER = frozenset("`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./")
ORDER = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + ' \b\r\t'
ALTER = dict(zip('!@#$%^&*()', '1234567890'))
OTHER = {'`': VK_OEM_3,
         '~': VK_OEM_3,
         '-': VK_OEM_MINUS,
         '_': VK_OEM_MINUS,
         '=': VK_OEM_PLUS,
         '+': VK_OEM_PLUS,
         '[': VK_OEM_4,
         '{': VK_OEM_4,
         ']': VK_OEM_6,
         '}': VK_OEM_6,
         '\\': VK_OEM_5,
         '|': VK_OEM_5,
         ';': VK_OEM_1,
         ':': VK_OEM_1,
         "'": VK_OEM_7,
         '"': VK_OEM_7,
         ',': VK_OEM_COMMA,
         '<': VK_OEM_COMMA,
         '.': VK_OEM_PERIOD,
         '>': VK_OEM_PERIOD,
         '/': VK_OEM_2,
         '?': VK_OEM_2}

def keyboard_stream(string):
    mode = False
    for character in string.replace('\r\n', '\r').replace('\n', '\r'):
        if mode and character in LOWER or not mode and character in UPPER:
            yield Keyboard(VK_SHIFT, mode and KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
            mode = not mode
        character = ALTER.get(character, character)
        if character in ORDER:
            code = ord(character.upper())
        elif character in OTHER:
            code = OTHER[character]
        else:
            continue
            #Or, to abort on unavailable character
            #raise ValueError('String is not understood!')
        yield Keyboard(code)
        yield Keyboard(code, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
    if mode:
        yield Keyboard(VK_SHIFT, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)

################################################################################

import time, sys

def main():
    time.sleep(5)
    for event in keyboard_stream('o2E^uXh#:SHn&HQ+t]YF'):
        SendInput(event)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
##if __name__ == '__main__':
##    main()

def switch_program():
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU), Keyboard(VK_TAB))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_TAB, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP),
              Keyboard(VK_MENU, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)

def select_line():
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_SHIFT, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY),
              Keyboard(VK_END, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_SHIFT, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP),
              Keyboard(VK_END, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)

def copy_line():
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL), Keyboard(KEY_C))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP),
              Keyboard(KEY_C, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)

def next_line():
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_HOME), Keyboard(VK_DOWN))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_HOME, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP),
              Keyboard(VK_DOWN, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)

def prepare_text():
    # Open Text
    SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_M))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_M, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # Goto Area
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_TAB))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_TAB, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # Paste Message
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL), Keyboard(KEY_V))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP),
              Keyboard(KEY_V, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # Goto Button
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_TAB))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_TAB, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.2)

def send_one_message():
    select_line()
    copy_line()
    next_line()
    switch_program()
    prepare_text()
    # Send Message
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_RETURN))
    time.sleep(0.2)
    SendInput(Keyboard(VK_RETURN, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(10)
    switch_program()
    
def send_messages(total):
    time.sleep(10)
    for _ in range(total):
        send_one_message()
```

Comment: I Tried:
`def hold_down_m_key():
    SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_M))
    #Also tried: SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_M, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY)) 
    time.sleep(3)
    SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_M, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
hold_down_m_key()`
This only sends the M key once, I also tried with other parameters for example shift, when VK_SHIFT is used it will hold the shift down forever and not use the 'KEYEVENTF_KEYUP'

Comment: @inControl Did you ever get this code to work for you, or did you still need help with something else?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower It has been a long time ago since i've asked this question or worked with python. As far as I can remember the code never worked as intended. A key like the 'P' key on the keyboard didn't simulate a 'P' down for a given duration. That is why I never accepted any answers.

Comment: The code works well under normal circumstances, however when I use it to enter a text in a window that is within VIrtualBox the result is completely random and 'Hi\r\n' suddenly becomes 'q89='. Any suggestions what could be causing this?

Comment: @Nicolas It is not clear to me why it would not work, but you might try [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and see if the `SendRaw` command works as expected with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, how can you simulate a key hold with this code?  I have not been able to get that to work with this either.

Comment: @DuckPuncher That is a good question. My expectation was that `SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A))` would press and hold the `A` key down until executing `SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))`, but that does not appear to work as intended. Maybe Microsoft expects developers to use some other API instead.

Comment: its qwerty and azerty problem i think 0x11 = w in qwerty and = z in azerty
beside that [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx] never helped

Comment: If I were just looking to send two keystrokes, no mouse or anything like that, would I still need this whole long set of code? My issue is the app I am looking to send keys to is not recognizing the control key in SendKeys or when I used keybd_event

Comment: @Mknerr My suggestion would be to start at the line `return Input(HardwareInput(message, parameter))` and use everything above. The code below is just an example of how to use it.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Thanks, I really appreciate the quick response! Most of this is fairly new to me. I'm looking to send a "Control + Space" to a 3rd party app that has so far not recognized any virtual keys I've sent it. If I wanted to mimic the hardware itself being pressed, which function should I use? (Apologies for the simple question, but there are a number of hardware-related functions in the code above)

Comment: Ahh it's just what i looking. I couldn't figure out how to use mouse. Anyone can help me please ? I need one example for mouse click on certain x,y location. Thanks!

Comment: `def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 22):

If you're using Python for Windows then there's a very good chance that you have the `win32api` module, which handles hooking into the API for you...

```py
import win32api
import win32con
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.SHIFT_PRESSED, 0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)
```

Does that help? (p.s. you should install IPython if, at all possible, it's massively helpful for experimenting)

Comment: Thanks a lot that works, but I really nead a character key to be pressed for example 'x' can't find the constants for win32con anywhere, please help.

Comment: `import win32con; dir(win32con)`, if you want a char key you can do `ord('x')`

Comment: user ord('x') where? something like this: win32api.keybd_event(ord('x'), 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)

Comment: Yes, you should check out the Windows API documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note, this answer can be used in conjunction with Noctis Skytower's answer to trigger any key, e.g.: `win32api.keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0,0,0)` (where `VK_RETURN` was taken from a definition in Noctis Skytower's solution).

Comment: you may well want a KEY_UP too `win32api.keybd_event( VK_RETURN,0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)` , possibly with a slight time delay in between `time.sleep(.05)`

Comment: There's a full dictionary of key codes and a great example function here: https://gist.github.com/chriskiehl/2906125

Answer (score 10):

I know that this question is really old, but I found a nice library: `PyUserInput`.
I am not sure how to download it in windows(I haven't downloaded libraries for windows for a long time). In Linux is easy just download pip(if you haven't):`sudo apt-get install pip` and then `sudo pip install pyuserinput`.
And then the code is realy simple:

```
#imports the library
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
#import the sleep function
from time import sleep
#initialize the keyboard simulator
keyboard = PyKeyboard()
#presses the key
keyboard.press_key('x')
#waits five seconds before releasing the key
sleep(5)
#releases the key
keyboard.release_key('x')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pip is usable in windows as well, sounds promising, I will try this somewhere in the next two weeks.

Comment: found this really useful, to trigger keyboard event in pygame. thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think this works in Python 3. The download says that it needs to install pyHook, which it says doesn't exist. `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from pyuserinput) (from versions: )`

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises I'm a little late, but try downloading a whl file for pyhook from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook then install it with pip.

Comment: New version update: you need to import like this: ```from pykeyboard.mac import PyKeyboard```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pynput` library which is easy to use.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller as keyboard_controller
keyboard = keyboard_controller()

keyboard.type("Please enter your desired key's code (HEX): ")
```

You can also simulate mouse even with this library.

Comment: why did this not get accepted? its a lot better than the answer now accepted

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the Noctis answer to work with Unicode characters.

"Simple unicode keyboard automation for windows"
https://gist.github.com/ubershmekel/4b414a66037feaea595b5f4e78220aad

The above link has a gist, this is the code from that gist today:

```
# coding: utf-8
"""
Simple unicode keyboard automation for windows
Based off of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown
"""

import ctypes
import time
import sys

LONG = ctypes.c_long
DWORD = ctypes.c_ulong
ULONG_PTR = ctypes.POINTER(DWORD)
WORD = ctypes.c_ushort

INPUT_MOUSE = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2

KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004


class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('dx', LONG),
                ('dy', LONG),
                ('mouseData', DWORD),
                ('dwFlags', DWORD),
                ('time', DWORD),
                ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR))


class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('wVk', WORD),
                ('wScan', WORD),
                ('dwFlags', DWORD),
                ('time', DWORD),
                ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR))


class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('uMsg', DWORD),
                ('wParamL', WORD),
                ('wParamH', WORD))


class _INPUTunion(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = (('mi', MOUSEINPUT),
                ('ki', KEYBDINPUT),
                ('hi', HARDWAREINPUT))


class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('type', DWORD),
                ('union', _INPUTunion))


def send_input(*inputs):
    nInputs = len(inputs)
    LPINPUT = INPUT * nInputs
    pInputs = LPINPUT(*inputs)
    cbSize = ctypes.c_int(ctypes.sizeof(INPUT))
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(nInputs, pInputs, cbSize)


def input_structure(structure):
    if isinstance(structure, MOUSEINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_MOUSE, _INPUTunion(mi=structure))
    if isinstance(structure, KEYBDINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_KEYBOARD, _INPUTunion(ki=structure))
    if isinstance(structure, HARDWAREINPUT):
        return INPUT(INPUT_HARDWARE, _INPUTunion(hi=structure))
    raise TypeError('Cannot create INPUT structure!')


def keyboard_input(code, flags):
    return KEYBDINPUT(0, code, flags, 0, None)


def keyboard_event(code, flags=KEYEVENTF_UNICODE):
    return input_structure(keyboard_input(code, flags))


def press(character):
    code = ord(character)
    send_input(keyboard_event(code))
    send_input(keyboard_event(code, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))


def main():
    time.sleep(3)
    for char in u'O\nשש2E6UXoשש2E^uXh#:SHn&HQ':
        press(char)
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```