# automatic press key in Python

Tags: python, button, sendkeys

im currently trying to make a auto-clicker and then a auto-button presser.

this is my code until now.

```
new=2;
url="www.google.com";

webbrowser.open(url,new=new);

time.sleep(25)


def click(x,y):
          win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
          win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
          win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(700,300)

time.sleep(3)
```

And after time.sleep(3) I want the spacebar to be pressed automatic (with 3sec sleep in between) 100 times. I have tried sendkeys, but cant find any download place.

Sorry for bad english, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076207/simulating-a-key-press-event-in-python-2-7) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown) might help you out, you should probably search these things and check if similar questions already exist before posting.