# How to hold key down with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, input, keyboard, simulate

I am using Selenium with Python and Chrome.  I am trying to hold down various keys -- specifically "w, a, s, and d."  I have found Selenium's action_chains.key_press action as well as the elem.send_keys method.  The problem with the first method is that it only holds the key down for as long as it takes to complete an action chain.  The problem with the elem.send_keys method is that it does not have an element to send the keys to.

I am trying to control a web-browser based robot with W-A-S-D, so I need to hold keys down for varying durations.

I have tried the following:

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.key_down("w")
action_chains.key_up("w")
```

as well as:

```
action_chains.key_press(elem, "w")
for x in range (0, 100):
    action_chains.perform()
    time.sleep(.01)
```

Neither are ideal.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're saying that `action_chains.key_down("w")` didn't work? Or did you need a method of lifting the key after some time has elapsed?

Comment: `action_chains.key_down("w")` does work, but only for the split second it takes for my computer to do that action.  Obviously the designers of the package made it take the minimum time possible.  I need a way to hold it down and then release after some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python simulate keydown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

Answer (score 6):

The current driver for Chrome (version 2.30) implements the previous protocol where holding a key is only supported for a modifier key (Control, Shift, Alt, Command).

So this code works with Firefox but **fails with Chrome** since the `keyUp` event is emitted for each `keyDown`:

```
action_key_down_w = ActionChains(driver).key_down("w")
action_key_up_w = ActionChains(driver).key_up("w")

endtime = time.time() + 1.0

while True:
  action_key_down_w.perform()

  if time.time() > endtime:
    action_key_up_w.perform()
    break
```

But, since version 2.30, the Chrome driver supports the `send_command` to directly send a raw command via the devtools protocol.
So as a workaround, you can call [Input.dispatchKeyEvent](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/) to emit low level events.

This is a working example with Selenium/Chrome to hold the key `w` during a second:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json, time

def dispatchKeyEvent(driver, name, options = {}):
  options["type"] = name
  body = json.dumps({'cmd': 'Input.dispatchKeyEvent', 'params': options})
  resource = "/session/%s/chromium/send_command" % driver.session_id
  url = driver.command_executor._url + resource
  driver.command_executor._request('POST', url, body)

def holdKeyW(driver, duration):
  endtime = time.time() + duration
  options = { \
    "code": "KeyW",
    "key": "w",
    "text": "w",
    "unmodifiedText": "w",
    "nativeVirtualKeyCode": ord("W"),
    "windowsVirtualKeyCode": ord("W")
  }

  while True:
    dispatchKeyEvent(driver, "rawKeyDown", options)
    dispatchKeyEvent(driver, "char", options)

    if time.time() > endtime:
      dispatchKeyEvent(driver, "keyUp", options)
      break

    options["autoRepeat"] = True
    time.sleep(0.01)


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")

# set the focus on the targeted element
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=q]").click()

# press the key W during a second
holdKeyW(driver, 1.0)
```

Comment: Excellent! Meanwhile, it's Ok for me to use Firefox, but why this information is missing from everywhere? And I still doesn't understand what is the problem for Chrome, to support this action! It's so usefull for some situation, like Canvas Fields, where you need to test different Keyboard Input.

Comment: The protocol has changed a lot between Selenium 2 and 3, especially for the chained actions. You can find this information by reading the old and the new spec. I don't know why Chrome hasn't moved to the new api. Might be resource/budget issue.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium actions chain Should only be used with modifier keys (Control, Alt and Shift). So you want to press only the character w-a-s-d. so that, it didn't work.

You can use any gui automation tools like pyautogui, etc.

please try below code and let me know.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 10
pyautogui.keyDown('w')
pyautogui.keyUp('w')
```

pyautogui.PAUSE=10 command make 10 seconds pause after each PyAutoGUI call

Comment: I need some possible solution on Selenium. To make sure, this action is appears only in Web PageWindow. But not in other places.

Comment: This action takes place on where ever the cursor is. Before this code you can make the browser window active using selenium. And selenium action chain operation require brower should be the top window. Otherwise key board and mouse operations will not work.

Comment: I didn't use Action Chain action before, but other action, like WebDriver.send_keys() works without problem, whenever Chrome Window is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Selenium Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.key_down) for `key_down`, it states:

> Should only be used with modifier keys (Control, Alt and Shift).

I've searched through the docs for an alternative solution, but it appears the behavior to "hold down" non-modifier keys is not possible in Selenium.

Comment: It's just like warning in Selenium. Calling` key_down ` works for other Keys, but only like clicking, and not holding (and I don't know, why).

Comment: @GensaGames Sometimes (unfortunately) the answer to these kinds of questions is simply "It's not possible". You can definitely request it as a new feature or contribute the feature yourself here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/www.seleniumhq.org/issues

Comment: @GensaGames Can you please describe the behavior you are trying to test?

Comment: Try to test Canvas changes. For ex. https://chromedino.com/ where need to hold Keys.ARROW_DOWN action for some time.

Comment: @GensaGames I haven't done any projects that require testing keydown events on a canvas before, but I don't believe Selenium would be the right tool for this. I would consider using a different automation tool.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionChains(driver).key_down("w").pause(0.1).key_up("w").perform()`

By chaining `key_down` and `key_up` with a `.pause(0.1)` in between you can hold down keys for any custom duration.

Even though `key_down` should only be used with modifier keys according to the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.key_down), it turns out that it can be used with any key.