# Python: Simulate keypress at hardwarelevel

Tags: python, linux, arm

I have a Raspberry Pi with the RetroPie v2 image.
After I installed xboxdrv and configured the controller, I searched a way to use the guide button to simulate the "escape" button.

I already have a python script which detects if I press the guide button.

I just need to know how I can simulate the escape button at hardware level.

Comment: [Quick n' dirty](http://cdn.instructables.com/FRV/4SD6/GZ0JID05/FRV4SD6GZ0JID05.LARGE.jpg)

Comment: Ok, and how can I realize it with an headless system :D

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11906925/645270) could help

Comment: It contains Win32 libs. I have a Debian-based distro for ARM processors.

Comment: Not Python, but take a look at java.awt.robot

Comment: Ok: Your java solution didn't work because I the X server isn't running while RetroPie is active. UInput failed to run at hardware level.