# Python Keypress code

Tags: python

I have found a Keypress Code from Noctis Skytower but I can't simulate ASCII keys like ø or Ø.

The code I mean is in the answer of Noctis Skytower:

[Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

I have tried

```
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU))
SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_1),Keyboard(KEY_5),Keyboard(KEY_5))
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
```

and

```
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU),Keyboard(KEY_1))
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU),Keyboard(KEY_5))  
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU),Keyboard(KEY_5))
```

and

```
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU))
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU),Keyboard(KEY_1))
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU),Keyboard(KEY_5))  
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU),Keyboard(KEY_5))
SendInput(Keyboard(VK_MENU,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
```

but all samples don't work.

Comment: "all samples don't work" - in what way do they not work? Do you get errors? It's hard for someone to help based on such a vague problem report.

Comment: no i get no errors but the ALT key don´t stay pressed until the KEYUP event. With the SHIFT key there is no problem and it work well. It is like i KEYUP after each Command line but i need for ascii keys to stay the key pressed that is my problem.