# Transcribing MIDI files to piano rolls in python (numpy)

Tags: python, midi, piano, music-notation

The following webpage http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~boulanni/icml2012 mentions that it is possible to convert MIDI files to piano rolls in python:

> Below are the source files (MIDI) for the 4 datasets evaluated in the
>   paper (split in train, validation and test sets). You can generate
>   piano-rolls from the source files by transposing each sequence in C
>   major or C minor and sampling frames every eighth note (quarter note
>   for JSB chorales) following the beat information present in the MIDI
>   file. Alternatively, pickled piano-rolls for use with the Python
>   language are also provided.

They have done it for a few examples. I would like to know how to do it but I cannot find in their code-base anywhere where it is done. Is there a simple way to do this?

So I know from [How to convert midi files to keypresses (in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011678/how-to-convert-midi-files-to-keypresses-in-python) that I can do

```
import midi
midi.read_midifile('example.mid')
```

that will return me a pattern of the likes of

```
midi.Pattern(format=1, resolution=220, tracks=\
[midi.Track(\
  [midi.NoteOnEvent(tick=0, channel=0, data=[43, 20]),
   midi.NoteOffEvent(tick=100, channel=0, data=[43, 0]),
   midi.EndOfTrackEvent(tick=1, data=[])])])
```

But then how do I transpose the sequence in C major or minor and how do I sample frames every eighth note?

So it seams that in the code referenced above, they do:

```
from midi.utils import midiread, midiwrite
midiread(midi_file, (21, 109), 0.3).piano_roll
```

So then my question becomes, where do I find those `midi.utils` and how do I assure that the sequence is transposed in the right key and sampled at the right rate?

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that they have a modified version of the original midi library (https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) which creates piano rolls. And the modified version of the code can be found here: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/deep/midi.zip .