# Paste a string into selected text field in Gnome using Python

Tags: python, events, keyboard, clipboard, keypress

I need to write a Python script to paste a defined string into selected text field inside current executed program (don't change the source of the program). It should behave like I've pressed the key on keyboard.

I've seen this [Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown), and eventually this is the thing I want to do, but the problem is the characters I want to type in are not in the standard keyboard layout.

So, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is my final solution (based on the previous answer and using python-uinput). It uses the ability to type Unicode symbols by pressing Ctrl+Shift+U then typing the hex code of the symbol.

Here is the Python script I wrote for it:

import uinput, time

```
allKeys = [uinput.KEY_LEFTSHIFT, uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, uinput.KEY_SPACE, uinput.KEY_U,
          uinput.KEY_A, uinput.KEY_B, uinput.KEY_C, uinput.KEY_D,
          uinput.KEY_E, uinput.KEY_F, uinput.KEY_0, uinput.KEY_1,
          uinput.KEY_2, uinput.KEY_3, uinput.KEY_4, uinput.KEY_5,
          uinput.KEY_6, uinput.KEY_7, uinput.KEY_8, uinput.KEY_9]

device = uinput.Device(allKeys)

sleepInterval = 0.003

def printChar(charCode):
  time.sleep(sleepInterval)
  device.emit(uinput.KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 1);
  device.emit(uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, 1);
  device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_U);
  device.emit(uinput.KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 0);
  device.emit(uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, 0);
  time.sleep(sleepInterval)

  for symbol in charCode:
    device.emit_click(uinput._chars_to_events(symbol)[0]);
    time.sleep(sleepInterval)

  device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_SPACE);
  time.sleep(sleepInterval)

charString = "string that will be typed"
for char in charString:
  printChar('{:04x}'.format(ord(char)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at uinput.  It allows you to inject keystrokes, buttons, mouse movements, joystick movements, etc through the /dev/uinput device.

In Python, you'd do something like:

```
keys = [uinput.KEY_X, uinput.KEY_Y, uinput.KEY_Z]
device = uinput.Device(keys)

...

# Simulate key Y being pressed.
device.emit(uinput.KEY_Y, 1)
```

You'll need to get uinput, of course:

```
pip install python-uinput
```

And you may need to install uinput device if you don't have.

(Well, this is only a solution for Linux, I suspect, and unfortunately, I didn't ask what's your platform).