# why does simulating keypresses not work for alt+tab and ctrl+alt+del?

Tags: python, keyboard

so i wanted to try and simulate some key presses and i used the scripts found  here:

[Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

and

[Generate keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events)

when I run these scripts, although the buttons are being pressed, it does not bring up the change windows thing or ctrl alt del menu on windows 8.  however, on a windows 7 computer the alt tab did work.  Why does it not work on windows 8 and is there a way I can simulate these strokes?

Comment: use `pyautogui` module. It's the best for keyboard-mouse actions. And you could find tutorials easily.

Comment: @GLHF pyautogui still does not simulate alt tab or ctrl alt delete.  the buttons are pressed but its not invoking the special functions for windows.

Comment: It does. It does everything with keyboard+mouse. There are some functions in pyautogui for holding buttons. And it does work.

Comment: @GLHF are you sure? can you post the code for it then? because when I use keydown in pyautogui to try and simulate either alt tab or ctrl alt del it fails.  the buttons are pressed and held however it does not do window's special functions for those bindings.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ctypes,time

KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002

def PressKey(KeyUnicode):

    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, KeyUnicode, KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(KeyUnicode):

    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, KeyUnicode, KEYEVENTF_UNICODE|KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


def PressAltTab():

    ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #Alt
    ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0) #Tab

    time.sleep(2) #optional : if you want to see the atl-tab overlay

    ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0x0002, 0) #~Tab
    ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0x0002, 0) #~Alt

PressAltTab()
```

This works for `ALT`+`TAB`, at `PressAltTab()` you see `ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0)`, just find the right numbers for `ctrl` and `delete`. As you see `alt` is `0x12`

However, ctrl+alt+del is a special shortcut, there might be security reasons to block it from fake-pressing. At least that's what I saw in the forums.