# Make python write letters

Tags: python, ctypes

I was making a python project that could play online games and i had a problem. I wanted to make the computer create a user but to do so you had to write in a name. I tried using ctypes but that didnt work out because i couldnt find any way to write letters, only click and move the cursor. Does anyone know a way to make python take control over keyboard? I am thinking something like this:

```
import ctypes
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("www.url.com")

ctypes.key.a()
ctypes.key.c()
ctypes.key.c()
ctypes.key.enter()
```

Comment: You may want to check the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown

Comment: Have you looked into a browser driver like Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend pyautogui. It is as simple as `pyautogui.press('b')`.