# How to inject extra key presses into a keylogger?

Tags: winapi, keyboard, hook, setwindowshookex

I have a keylogger on my Win8 box. Nothing sinister: it performs some useful extra work. Actually it is so useful that I want to trigger some of its functions when I am afk. Naturally AutoIt and such does not work (I've checked): the logger is hooked to a low-level keyboard hook (I guess), and real keyboard hooks are not triggered by virtual keyboard events (I believe).

Basically I need a virtual keyboard with real-look-alike keypresses.

(Edit: I've deleted my own "idea" how to solve this, it was bad anyway, and I have more understanding now)

---

### Trying SendInput and why it does not work.

People suggested to try SendInput. In short: it does not work, because I've managed to raise integrity level of my pythonw.exe only to High, but the "keylogger" runs on System level, and, as said in [SendInput doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx)

> Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that
>   are at an equal or lesser integrity level.

I've found a very nice python SendInput implementation at  [Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown), in comments.
To check "integrity level" of the process you can use ProcessExplorer, View / Select Columns, check "Integrity Level".
ProcessExplorer shows my pythonw.exe which I "Run as Admin" at the IL "High", but AcrossServer, AcrossService and a spawned conhost.exe all have the IL "System". (Yes, I am trying to inject keys into the very nice Bluetooth keyboard simulator Across).

---

### Next possible steps.

1. Raising the integrity level of my app to System:

   - make it a windows service;
   - make it a device(less) driver;
   - anything easier? or
2. Lowing the integrity level of AcrossService to (at least) High:

   - is it possible? **Edit:** it is possible, Control Panel / Services, change logon account to myself. Unfortunately, Accross stops working when lowered.
3. Create a Python equivalent of Across Server on Windows.

Number 3 seem the most socially useful and seems easier than creating a specialized device driver :)  But am I missing some simpler possibilities?

Comment: [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable for pointing to SendInput doc. There was this significant info that I've overlooked previously: `Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level.` I've tried to use AutoHotKey script running "as Admin". No success so far, but that may be my error (tests are not very straightforward). I am going to play with Python interface to SendInput (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown in comments) and will post result.

Comment: Does not seem to work:  
1. I am checking that my Python code is running as Admin;  
2. I am sending "down" for RCONTROL and LCONTROL;  
3. I check GetAsyncKeyState for both (down) - then I send "up" for both - still the "keylogger" ignores my virtual key presses while performing ok on physical ones.