# How can I simulate xbox controller python?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to simulate gamepad input, and I cannot find the way to do it, since some people say that I need pyvjoy and I don't where can I get it, other people say that pygame/tkinter but I cant find any info in docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Simulate XBox Controller Input with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483121/simulate-xbox-controller-input-with-python)

You can get most of the python modules using **pip**
(more info here:https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/):

```
$ pip install <my_python_package_name>
```

But package "**pyvjoy**" from https://github.com/tidzo/pyvjoy
cannot be installed in this way, so you have to download it using **zip or via git** if you've got git installed:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tidzo/pyvjoy
```

Then you should try to run your python outside this directory (you should **have "pyvjoy" directory** in that folder **where you start your python** interpreter) and test it with:

```
>>> import pyvjoy
```

**This library currently only works with the x86 dll.**

Hope, it was helpful.