# Is there a way to send / press NUMPAD keys in python?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, mouse, emulation

So far I have tried pyautogui to send them, but it doesn't work. I was hoping because in the source code it shows this:

```
'num multiply': '*',
'num divide': '/',
'num add': '+',
'num plus': '+',
'num minus': '-',
'num sub': '-',
'num enter': 'enter',
'num 0': '0',
'num 1': '1',
'num 2': '2',
'num 3': '3',
'num 4': '4',
'num 5': '5',
'num 6': '6',
'num 7': '7',
'num 8': '8',
'num 9': '9',
```

but that didn't do anything other than what you might expect. It would do regular numbers, and not the numpad specific ones.

```
pyautogui.press("num 3")
```

for example, doesn't work at all, and

```
pyautogui.press("3")
```

just sends a 3

I have also tried win32api's SendKeys, but that doesn't have the numkeys listed at all, and going through the source code over there, it looks like they're included (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) but aren't supported in the Python implementation...so this doesn't work:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> import win32com.client
>>> shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
>>> shell.SendKeys("{NUMPAD7}")
```

that returns

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

I need to be able to use the numpad keys because I have a setup that uses an emulated mouse that I need to programatically control via those keys. I have figured out a workaround by disabling and re-enabling the emulation (I'm using NeatMouse) via a key-combination that works (and can be sent with SendKeys) because you rarely type and use the mouse at the same time, but I am still very curious about whether what I want to do is actually possible directly.

To reiterate, I want to directly press NUMPAD keys via python.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown

Answer (score 3):

Based on the official documentation: [PyAutoGUI - Keyboard Control Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)
it seems that the only problem with your code not working is the space in between "num" and "3". If the documentation is correct you should only change:

```
pyautogui.press("num 3")
```

to:

```
pyautogui.press("num3")
```