# Program to move mouse cursor doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, winapi, mouseevent

I'm creating a program that utilizes the `win32api` `mouse_event` to move the mouse cursor to a certain position. However, the program is not working as expected.
Any help would be most appreciated.

**NOTE**: I must use `win32api` and no other library.

Take this program for example:

```
import win32api

x = 1000
y = 1000
win32api.mouse_event(0x0001, int(x), int(y))
```

It should move the mouse cursor to the 1000th x and y pixels on the screen but it doesn't.

Comment: How about using [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead?

Comment: Read the documentation: [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event).

Comment: SendInput would be using a different library?

Comment: @mic: That doesn't change anything. It's just more setup to accomplish the same thing, with no benefit. The parameters and semantics are virtually identical.

Comment: I have read the documentation, I'm just curious as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: The documentation tells you all you need to know. You read it slowly, and in detail.

Comment: I have read it and it is a little confusing tbh. Do you have any ideas as to why the simple code excerpt above doesn't work?

Comment: Read what the documentation says about relative and absolute coordinates

Comment: Yes, I have I understand that the code above does not work because it is moving the mouse relative to its current position. That is why I want to use absolute position, however, I could not find any examples of the syntax to do this.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python#comment14114219_1181538) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SendInput`, you need to use the `ctypes` library, and if you use the old `mouse_event`, you can use the following example.

```
import win32api 
import win32con
def click(x,y):
    cx_screen = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSCREEN)
    cy_screen = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSCREEN) 
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, int(65535.0*x/cx_screen), int(65535.0*y/cy_screen))
click(1000,100)
```

[How to Use SendInput to realize Mouse Click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)