# How to send a XBUTTON1 or XBUTTON2 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

I have read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/mouse-clicks)

But in `win32con` module,there is no key called `WM_XBUTTONUP`.And I also find [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

And finally I found `win32con.VK_XBUTTON1` existed,But I didn't found `WM_XBUTTONUP`.I also found `VK_UP` so I tried to use it to replace `WM_XBUTTONUP`.

Now all my code is:

```
import win32api,win32con

win32api.mouse_event(win32con.VK_XBUTTON1|win32con.VK_UP,0,0,0,0)
```

But when I run it,My mouse button will don't work.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried use defined value 0x020C ([WM_XBUTTONUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-xbuttonup))?

Comment: I haven't,But now If I use `mouse_event`,My python will be not responding.

Comment: `mouse_event` function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

Comment: Sorry,It seems that `win32api` has no attribute `SendInput` and `Sendinput` and `sendInput`.

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown) to see if it helps.