# Button press when a word appears in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a program that will take a word from a .txt file and will press a keyboard key. I'm doing it so my Twitch chat can control my keyboard by a command. Below is the code without the key press (it doesn't work).

```
with open('C:\Users\laith\AppData\Roaming\HexChat\logs\Twitch\#liongenz9629.log') as file:
contents = file.read()
search_word = input("test2")
if search_word in contents:
    print ('word found')

else:
    print ('word not found')
```

I also can't figure out how to press a key. I tried including the following code:

```
Send {F down}{Fup}
Send {F down}{Fup}
```

to make this:

```
with open('C:\Users\laith\AppData\Roaming\HexChat\logs\Twitch\#liongenz9629.log') as file:
contents = file.read()
search_word = input("test2")
if search_word in contents:
    Send {F down}{Fup}
    Send {F down}{Fup}

else:
    print ('word not found')
```

But what I would like to know, is why it didn't work.
I researched it extensively and could not find a fix, so alas here I am...

I am using Python 2.7.18 64-Bit

---

PC:
Windows 10 Home Version 1903 Build 18362.959

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) package ? It should work on python 2.7.

To install execute

```
pip install pynput
```

Example from the documentation :

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

# Press and release space
keyboard.press(Key.space)
keyboard.release(Key.space)

# Type a lower case A; this will work even if no key on the
# physical keyboard is labelled 'A'
keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.release('a')

# Type two upper case As
keyboard.press('A')
keyboard.release('A')
with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
    keyboard.press('a')
    keyboard.release('a')

# Type 'Hello World' using the shortcut type method
keyboard.type('Hello World')
```