# Keys not holding down using various keyboard modules in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to simulate a key being held down for a specific amount of time using python. I first tried using the keyboard module to accomplish this like so:

```
import time
import keyboard

keyboard.press('space')
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.release('space')
```

This block of code will correctly press the space key but not hold it down. It taps space and then instantly releases it before time.sleep(5) is called. The space key is pressed and released once, the program waits 5 seconds, then does nothing and exits. I also tried using the pynput module to accomplish this task like so:

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.space)
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.release(Key.space)
```

The same exact issue arises. Space is pressed and then instantly released instead of being held down. I also tried using the AHK module:

```
import time
from ahk import AHK
ahk = AHK()

ahk.key_down('Space')
time.sleep(5)
ahk.key_up('Space')
```

None of these modules have worked for me. I've tested all of them by opening up a blank notepad and then running the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python simulate keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

Comment: That solution uses ctypes for simulating keypress. Please search all the existing questions and answers on this (search for *python simulate/simulating keypress*). There may well not be a package that does this, in which  case brew your own solution using ctypes or whatever.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue where the key is pressed down once and instantly released using this method.

Comment: Have you read through the [65 hits for *python simulate keypress*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+simulate+keypress), [46 hits for *python simulating keypress*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+simulating+keypress), plus other terms...  you're sure to find your answer. When you do, cite it here please.

Comment: do you have the same problem with other keys? Maybe problem is keyboard (hardware), not script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `pyautougui`. `Pyautogui` is a GUI great for automating the mouse and keyboard, as well as taking screenshots and finding images on screen (using PIL and Pillow). Please note that `pyautogui` *cannot* detect key presses or mouse movements, so you'll have to use a different library for that.

`Pyautogui` has the `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` functions which I think will be perfect for your use. For example:

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.keyDown('space') #holds space key down
time.sleep(5) #sleeps for 5 seconds
pyautogui.keyUp('space') #releases the space key
```

and this might work for you.

**Note:** When you run this code, most likely, you will get the output: " ", basically meaning that the space bar *appears* to have been pressed only once and immediately released. This is usually not the case, for some reason, you won't get the expected output: "many spaces typed repeatedly" like you'd expect. I don't know why this occurs, I think it has something to do with holding down a key and expecting it to continue typing. Like if the user holds down the key 'z', usually, you'd expect output: "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", as the computer continuously repeats typing the letter z, until the key is released. However, with `pyautogui`: "z". In my case at least, the key was being pressed. To truly test it out, I opened a web browser and opened an online free game, where the controls for the game involved needing the "w" key to be pressed and held. I wrote a `pyautogui` program to continously hold the "w" key, and the game worked, which is how I knew that the "w" key *was in fact* being held. If you truly wanted the output: "many spaces", you could just use pyautogui's typewrite function, like this: `pyautogui.typewrite("          ")`, or alternatively use the press function: `pyautogui.press(" ", presses=10)` with the presses argument.

There are several modules other than the ones you mentioned and `pyautogui` that can solve this problem, so I would recommend checking out https://pypi.org for more information.

Pyautogui: https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI