# How to pick items from context menu that are lower down

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, contextmenu

I am trying to right click on a link, and then click "Save link as" and then have the program type some name and save the link. However, whenever I open a context menu on a link, I am only able to choose the first or second option in the menu. More specifically, I can click on "Open link in new tab" and "Open link in new window", but not anything below that. 
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")

elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download for iOS on the App Store')

actionChains= ActionChains(driver);
time.sleep(3)
actionChains.context_click(elem).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ARROW_DOWN,'H').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: looks like you cant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835867/using-selenium-in-python-to-save-a-webpage-on-firefox

Comment: why do you `time.sleep` ?

Comment: The time sleep thing is a remnant from before, it does nothing so you can just ignore that

Comment: @DougClark Very well, but I'd still like to know just how to go down in the context menu beyond the first two options

Comment: from the linked post: "What you are trying to achieve is impossible to do with Selenium. The dialog that opens is not something Selenium can interact with." But here is another post i found that could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789188/how-to-navigate-context-menus-selenium-python

Comment: But if it's impossible to navigate, then how was I able to navigate to choose a new window instead of a new tab?