# Determine popup/new window type so I can interact with it in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

This may be a noob question, but I don't know how to determine what type of popup I am interacting with so I can have enough information to automate it using selenium webdriver.

I assumed it was just a popup, but when using (what seems to be) the standard way of dealing with popups my Selenium JUnit test freezes the instance the button is clicked.

```
    String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //P2: Click on the element that opens the popup
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();

    Set s=driver.getWindowHandles();

    Iterator ite=s.iterator();
    while(ite.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Current ite = " + ite.next().toString());
        String popupHandle=ite.next().toString();
        if(!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHandle)){
            driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
            System.out.println("reached popup window? Now perform the login procedure before returning to the original window");
            driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
```

This code [was described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188343/how-can-selenium-web-driver-get-to-know-when-the-new-window-has-opened-and-then) and was the accepted answer. I have also seen many other similar examples of this code, however in my application the selenium test hangs on line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();
```

It just waits for me to enter login info, and until I do that manually the test hangs. If I do enter the info the test continues. I want to have this code finding the handle of the popup window (and eventually) populating it with username and pass and clicking on 'ok'. Though could it be possible that I am not dealing with a traditional popup? How could I tell?

This login button is the following element in the html `<a href="/trac/login">Login</a>`

Comment: does it click login? If it hangs on that step, may be your not *finding* the login webelement correctly.

Comment: It does click login and the login prompt displays as expected.

Comment: so it does not hang on the step you mentioned in your question, so can u check again where exactly does your script fail/hang?

Comment: Sorry this is difficult for me to describe, but the code stops executing at the step I mention. The thing is that the test isn't dead at that point it is waiting for the login to happen before it will execute the next step if that makes sense. I can put any other step after clicking on login and it will not get executed until login happens thats why I call it hanging, but that might not be the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using selenium RC. I have used try catch block as shown below which helped me in solving the problem.
hope it will be useful.

//webdriver code till clicking the pop up link

```
try {
      selenium.waitForPopUp("myWindow","3000");
        }



    catch(Exception e){
        selenium.selectPopUp("myWindow");
        selenium.windowFocus();
```

//activity that needs to be performed on the pop up window***

//code that takes back the focus to main window

```
 String[] winFocus; 
 String winTitle;
 winFocus = selenium.getAllWindowTitles();
 winTitle = winFocus[0];
 selenium.selectWindow(winTitle);
```

}