# Selenide test not able to load correct element on a newly opened tab/window

Tags: groovy, spock, selenide

I am using [Selenide](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/wiki) to open a sample input form on w3schools.com (found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)).

The test inputs a name into the form and clicks submit, which then opens a new page in a separate tab/window which displays the request params in a div.

[image: Sample HTML form screenshot]

[image: Returned results screenshot]

The following is my test code:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration
import org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.configuration.StandaloneConfiguration
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer
import spock.lang.Specification

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.*
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selectors.byName
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selectors.byTitle
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*

class DummyTest extends Specification {

    def "Test w3schools form submit"() {
        given: "Server setup configurations"
            Configuration.browser = 'chrome'
            StandaloneConfiguration configuration = new StandaloneConfiguration()
            SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(configuration)
            server.boot()

        when: "Name info is submitted into the form"
            open("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp")
            $(byName("firstname")).setValue("Clark")
            $(byName("lastname")).setValue("Kent")
            $x('//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/form/input[3]').click()

            // Maybe this will fix the erroneous element problem?
            $(byTitle('HTML Forms')).waitUntil(disappears, 5000)

        then: "New page should display the passed-in request params"
            $x("/html/body/div[1]").shouldHave(text("firstname=Clark&lastname=Kent"))
    }
}
```

...where `webdriver.chrome.driver` is a passed-in environment variable pointing to the correct location of `chromedriver.exe`.

The test does open the initial form page and type in the first/last name correctly. When it clicks the submit button, it waits for the second page to load and display the request params.

As a note, the error happens regardless of whether or not my `waitUntil()` method call is present or not. Many of the other StackOverflow posts suggest doing something like that to fix the problem, though the Selenide docs say that the `shouldHave()` method call in my `then` clause should automatically do a fluent wait.

This is the output of my test case:

```
Condition failed with Exception:

$x("/html/body/div[1]").shouldHave(text("firstname=Clark&lastname=Kent"))
|                       |          |
|                       |          text 'firstname=Clark&lastname=Kent'
|                       Element should have text 'firstname=Clark&lastname=Kent' {By.xpath: /html/body/div[1]}
|                       Element: '<div class="w3-container top">w3schools.com
|                       THE WORLD'S LARGEST WEB DEVELOPER SITE</div>'
|                       Screenshot: file:/C:/Workspace/IntelliJ/dummy-selenide-project/build/reports/tests/1498836183270.0.png
|                       Timeout: 4 s.
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]"}
```

So, it's clear that, as per the test output, it's grabbing the xPath of the initial page, not the second page.

Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong? Do I need to instantiate a new object or something for every new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was difficult to find the answer in the docs, but I found out in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9188343/1530072) that you do need to call a method to switch to another window.

You must call the static method `Selenide#switchTo()`, which returns a `SelenideTargetLocator`. On that object, you can call the method `window()`, which either takes a 0-based index (`int`) or a name/handle/title (`String`).

So, after adding the `switchTo()` method in my `and` clause for my Spock test, the working result looks like this:

```
def "Test w3schools form submit"() {
    given: "Server setup configurations"
        Configuration.browser = 'chrome'
        StandaloneConfiguration configuration = new StandaloneConfiguration()
        SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(configuration)
        server.boot()

    when: "Name info is submitted into the form"
        open("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp")
        $(byName("firstname")).setValue("Clark")
        $(byName("lastname")).setValue("Kent")
        $x('//*[@id="main"]/div[3]/div/form/input[3]').click()

    and: "Switch to newly opened window"
        switchTo().window(1)

    then: "New page should display the passed-in request params"
        $x("/html/body/div[1]").shouldHave(text("firstname=Clark&lastname=Kent"))
}
```

**Note**: For sake of my test code, since the test only opens one new tab, calling `switchTo(1)` works fine here for Chrome, but note that the window/tab order may be different in other browsers.